# Read properties file on glassfish 4

Tags: java, glassfish, war

I need to read a properties file in a glassfish 4 application.  The file needs to be somewhere in the application (i.e. not at some random place in the file system).

If it matters, I'm developing with eclipse, the project builds with maven, and the artifact is a war.

It seems to me there are three things I need to know to make this work.

1) Where does the original file need to be?

2) Where does the file need to end up?

3) How do I read it?

So far I created the file:

```
src/main/resources/version.properties
```

which ends up in

```
WEB-INF/classes/version.properties
```

I don't know if that is the correct location.

Based on similar questions, I have defined a ServletContextListener:

```
public class ServletContextClass implements ServletContextListener {
...
   @Override
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
       ServletContext ctx = arg0.getServletContext();
       InputStream istream = ctx.getResourceAsStream("version.properties"); 

       // at this point, istream is null

       Properties p = new Properties();
       p.load(istream);
   }
}
```

I'm not sure if I have the file in the wrong place, if I'm reading it wrong, or both.

update: the following "works":

```
   @Override
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
       ResourceBundle bundle =  ResourceBundle.getBundle("version");
       if (bundle == null) { 
          logger.info("bundle is null");
       } else {
          logger.info("bundle is not null");
          logger.info("version: " + bundle.getString("myversion"));
       }
   }
```

However, I don't think this is the correct solution.  Bundles are for locale support, and this does not fall under that category.

Update 2: I corrected the location where the file ends up.

Answer (score 1):

1) Putting the version.properties file in

```
src/main/resources/version.properties
```

seems to be correct.

2) In the target war, the file does in fact end up in

```
WEB-INF/classes/version.properties
```

3) To read the file:  I already had a ServletContextListener defined.  If you don't you need to define one and configure it in web.xml.  Here is a portion of my ServletContextListener:

```
   package com.mycompany.service;

   public class ServletContextClass implements ServletContextListener {
        @Override
        public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
           ServletContext ctx=arg0.getServletContext();

           try {
              Properties p = new Properties();
              InputStream istream = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/classes/version.properties");
              p.load(istream);
              Properties sysProps = System.getProperties();
              sysProps.putAll(p);
          } catch (IOException e) {
              logger.error("Error reading " + "version.properties");
          }
       }
    }
```

It is configured with this piece of the web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.mycompany.service.ServletContextClass</listener-class>
</listener>
```